# jstree : move multiple nodes, data.rslt.op is not an array

Tags: parent, move, jstree

If I move multiple nodes I get the array of selected nodes
with data.rslt.o but data.rslt.op (old parents) is always a 1 element array.
How can I get the old parent of every moved node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known open issue/bug. Check this out...

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/99

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jstree/d8wnINfrAuw